# Finding prime numbers within range using math.sqrt

Tags: python

So I have to find prime numbers from 1 to 500
I checked various blogs and stack overflow questions
but every time I change my code it returns
"1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9"
I can't find the problem. Please help me.

```
primary = True
import math
for n in range(2,501):
    sqrn=math.sqrt(n)
    for div in range (2, int(sqrn)):
        if n%div == 0:
            primary = False
            break
    if primary:
        print(n, end=" ")
print()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add 1 to `sqrt(n)`, because `range`’s upper bound is *exclusive*.

Furthermore, you need to reset `primary` to `True` before every inner loop, otherwise you’ll only ever find a single prime.

```
import math

for n in range(2, 501):
    primary = True
    sqrn = math.sqrt(n)
    for div in range (2, int(sqrn) + 1):
        if n % div == 0:
            primary = False
            break
    if primary:
        print(n, end=" ")

print()
```